# ModuleNotFoundError at /polls/register/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a registration form in django. My project name is FirstProj containing mysite and mysite containing polls.
My forms.py is this

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email= forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

My views.py is this

```
from mysite.polls.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/polls')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'polls/reg_form.html', args)
```

However my cleaned_data() can't be read and i am getting the following erro.

```
No module named 'mysite.polls'
```

[image: This is my folder tree]

[image: Here's my error]

My urls.py in mysite is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace= "polls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and, my urls.py in polls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login,logout

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name= "index"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name= "detail"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
    # 127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    # 127.0.0.1/polls/1/vote
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'polls/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'polls/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name= 'register'),
]
```

Comment: I don't understand, could you print your folders tree ? I think the issue is there.

Comment: Why did you manually altered the save method? Did you added your app to the project settings INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Add the entire error stack trace

Comment: I have added a folder tree. Do answer.

Comment: have u added app name in INSTALLED_APP section of settings.py?

Comment: Yes. I have added the app name as 'polls' in installed apps

Comment: Add `__init__.py` file under polls folder

Comment: There is _init_.py under polls folder

Comment: I cannot see in the tree structure you posted, one `__init__.py` is inside `templates` folder but not inside `firstproj\mysite\polls` folder

Comment: No. _init_.py is actually inside polls folder not inside templates

Comment: paste `urls.py` file as well for both `mysite` as well as for `polls`

Comment: i have pasted urls.py of both mysite and polls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164080/discussion-between-anuragal-and-arpan-mahatra).

Answer (score 3):

Can you try changing this `from mysite.polls.forms import RegistrationForm` to this `from polls.forms import RegistrationForm`

The problem is that `polls` is not a module of your project `mysite` so by typing `mysite.polls` django tries to search something under the project and don't find anything (a module is something like `polls.forms` or `polls.models` where `forms` and `models` are the modules of the app `polls`.

Comment: @arpanmahatra glad to hear it, please if you liked the answer accept it!

Comment: @arpanmahatra I've improved the answer